# Python 2d list generator in one line

Tags: python, generator

I have a matrix of numbers in a file (distances between cities for solving TSP). I load it up into a list. After that each row in my list looks like this:

```
' 9999    3    5   48   48    8    8    5    5    3    3    0    3    5    8    8    5\n'
```

The number of whitespaces between numbers may be different on each line. Now I just want to convert it to a list of lists of ints/floats. I got that with a loop:

```
matrix = []
for row in lines[begin:end]:
    matrix.append([float(x) for x in row.split()])
```

It works just fine. I am just curious if I can use a generator here (like I use it in loop), but not in loop, but in one line. I tried something like `[float(x) for x in [y.split() for y in lines[begin:end]]]`, but it says:

```
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

So can it be solved like in one line, or should I leave it in loop?

Comment: That is not a generator, that is a *list comprehension*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following list comprehension

```
matrix = [[float(i) for i in row.split()] for row in lines]
```

But for this particular case, it would be much faster to use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.genfromtxt('your_file', delimeter=' ')
```

Comment: Cannot use that, cuz at the beginning of the file I got some non-number data, basically text :D

Comment: There is an argument [`skip_header`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to skip N number of lines at the beginning

Comment: But then if I have like 100 files like this and the number of lines to skip can vary, then I cannot specify this :D Or I have to count by myself

Comment: @Frynio This is a different question though.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.

```
my_list = [' 9999    3    5   48   48    8    8    5    5    3    3    0    3    5    8    8    5\n', 
           ' 3    12    5   48   48    8    8    5    5    3    3    0    3    5    8    8    5\n']

gen = (list(map(float, f.split())) for f in my_list)
```

You can now iterate over `gen`.

For example:

```
for i in gen:
  print(i)
```

- First iteration returns: `[9999.0, 3.0, 5.0, 48.0, 48.0, 8.0, ...]`
- Second one:              `[3.0, 12.0, 5.0, 48.0, 48.0, 8.0, ...]`

---

I am assuming that by `generator` you actually mean `generator` by the way and not `list-comprehension`. If that is not the case, the answer by @Cody is the way to go.

Comment: Ah, my fault, wrote generator and I just wanted anything that works in one line like this :P

Comment: @Frynio One-liners are over-rated. "Readability counts". But generator expressions can be useful when you don't need to build a large structure in RAM.